# Lineman - Running "watch" task Aborted due to warning

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to run Lineman (https://github.com/testdouble/lineman) and when it gets to the "watch" task it throws a warning that then causes the app to Abort. Anyone else run into this?

... error ...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening because I was running node v. 0.10.3 and there are some issues with the latest version. After I downgraded to 0.8.x it started working.